# MySQL metadata scheme not showing in Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

As you can see in the image below, I am using a JDBC connexion in Jaspersoft Studio. The connexion WORKS FINE, I can query my tables (select * from art), and even create the report whitout any problems. Unfortunately, the scheme on the left is not showing (No Metadata.). And as it is a big MySQL database, I would have liked to have the names of the tables appearing. I cannot install other softwares (such as MySQL Workbench, or Open Modelsphere) to help me view the database.
Does anybody know if this is a software bug?

[image: Jaspersoft metadata scheme error]

Comment: Did you check the Studio's logs?

Comment: Did you check the queries like `SHOW DATABASES` or `SHOW TABLES` under the user used in connection string?

Comment: The text `/ by zero` is the exception message of an ArithmeticException thrown by Java when you attempt to divide an integer by zero or take the remainder after division by zero.  I suspect a software bug here.